# How can I systematically disable certain irrelevant a11y warnings when compiling with Svelte?

Tags: accessibility, svelte, rollupjs, svelte-3

Here is the warning I get when I compile a component with an img that lacks an alt attribute:

```
Plugin svelte: A11y: <img> element should have an alt attribute
```

All developers will agree A11y is a good thing; except in my case, it would serve only to annoy a screen reader. I'm making a game engine and my objects look like this:

[image: Example]

SVG image, item label. To the screen reader, this would read "Fabric Scrap Fabric Scrap"; it really doesn't make sense to have an alt attribute here, but the best the docs have to offer me is that I can clutter up my code like such:

```
<!-- svelte-ignore a11y-autofocus -->
<input bind:value={name} autofocus>
```

I really want to avoid that, so how can I get Svelte to stop showing me this specific error? Ideally without disabling the A11y module as a whole.

Comment: If this is an SVG loaded via an external call (i.e. not inline in the HTML) you MUST have an alt attribute. The warning you are seeing is because you have left the alt attribute off or have made it null (either `<img/>` or `<img alt/>`). You must use `alt=""` so that a screen reader does not announce an image. Leaving it off will then read the file name. Obviously if this SVG is inline within you HTML and not reference via an `<img>` tag then this is irrelevant (but at that point I would guess svelte wouldn't be complaining).

Comment: Why would you want to disable valid a11y warnings?

Comment: Ah, good to know about the empty `alt=""` @GrahamRitchie. It would still muddy up the code, though, and I'm going with the selected answer. Nathaniel: please read my question to see why these warnings are indeed irrelevant (actually, worse) in my application.

Comment: It doesn't work like that, you must have an alt tag as described (`alt=""`) if the image is being loaded externally. If you don't it will be awful for screen reader users and at that point there is no point in running accessibility tests at all. You don't get to decide how clean your code looks sadly. You are concerned about 'Fabric Scrap Fabric Scrap' annoying screen reader users but how do you think 'https://yourdomain/assets/images/icons/fabric-scrap.svg Fabric Scrap' would sound on a screen reader? That is how it sounds if you do not add a `alt=""` attribute.

Comment: @GrahamRitchie I missed the line, "Leaving it off will then read the file name." Yikes! I've had a look around the web and confirmed this is true; though I suspect it might be possible to disable per-site. I will be a good boy and add all those alt='' now. Thank you!

Comment: yet again that would be great if we could disable per site, i.e missing alt tag is equivalent to `alt=""` but sadly we can't. No probs bud, good luck with the game!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can disable warnings at the project level.

If you're using rollup, warnings can be suppressed by providing a custom `onwarn` handler:

```js
import svelte from 'rollup-plugin-svelte'

export default {
  plugins: [
    svelte({
      // Warnings are normally passed straight to Rollup. You can
      // optionally handle them here, for example to squelch
      // warnings with a particular code
      onwarn: (warning, handler) => {
        // e.g. don't warn on a11y-autofocus
        if (warning.code === 'a11y-autofocus') return

        // let Rollup handle all other warnings normally
        handler(warning)
      }
    })
  ]
}
```

Comment: Thanks! Note it might actually be `warning.pluginCode`. 

For ambiguous pluginCodes, just check in this way: `warning.message.includes('your error msg')`

Comment: how can I do it in sveltekit ?